# dynamically build the class attributes from the dictionary

Tags: python

I want to build the class attributes dynamically.

```
# Code  
label = Label();  
label.port = 'JTAG';  ##works  

# Attribute name in a variable  
field_name = 'port';  
label.field_name = 'port'; ## do not work.  

# Foreign key mapping.    
label.foreign_key.port_name = 'port'; ## should work for foreign_key
```

I do not want to use `setattr` here because i mapped the foreign key object to this object. where `setattr` fails for foreign keys.

Finally i want to interpolate the 'field_name' variable while building the class object attributes dynamically. Please let me know the method without using `setattr`.

Comment: Is `Label()` a class you defined yourself or a given class of some module? As a starting point you might have a look at `**kwargs` in combination with `class.__init__()` and, additionally, at  inheritance in order to add further attributes to a given class.

Comment: this question is very unclear and thus I flagged it.

Answer (score 0):

the following would do the trick:

```
label.__dict__[field_name] = 'port'
```

all attributes of a custom class instance is stored as a dictionary internally as `obj.__dict__`

Comment: from dictionary key i want to retreive the attribute value in pyhtho without using setattr and __dict__ . Here i think that the dict key has to be interpolated first before adding it as a class attribute. Why i do not want to use setattr here is i can do update if it is a foreign key as well.